# Finding an uppercase letter, number, parentheses, and colon in string

Tags: regex

I have a txt file that is exported from a webapp that is formatted as a list of strings:

```
['D) Cable Tricep Extension:  | WARMUP:',
'⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺',
'1 x 10-18 @3 to @4',
'',
'',
'↓ WORKING SETS:',
'⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺',
'❍ 3 x 10-18 @8 to @9',
'',
'⎋ REST: 1-2 min',
'30x14 @7.5',
'30x12 @8 x2 sets',
'E1) Session RPE: Choose a number between 1 and 10 indicating how hard the training session was (scale provided below).']
```

I'm looking to find the index of every line that starts with a an uppercase letter, is immediately followed by either a number or end parenthese, immediately followed by a space, and then in an unknown number of characters between, a colon. So in this example, I would need the following lines to produce a match:

```
['D) Cable Tricep Extension:  | WARMUP:',
'E1) Session RPE: Choose a number between 1 and 10 indicating how hard the training session was (scale provided below).']
```

I've used regex to no luck. I need the regex to be as specific as possible as to not match other text. I've tried '^[A_Z][1-9]|[) ]*:' which works, but if I remove the parentheses from the lines I'm trying to match it still matches the line (meaning the regex I wrote is too greedy).

Comment: Why should `['D) Cable Tricep Extension:  | WARMUP:',` match? It doesn't *start with an uppercase letter* - it starts with a square bracket. Similar question for `'E1) Session RPE: Choose a number between 1 and 10 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `^[A_Z][1-9]|[) ]*:` is not per se too greedy, but it uses an unanchored alternation in the second part that matches optional spaces or `)` followed by `:`

So if you remove the parenthesis in the example data, the `:` will still match.

Note that `[A_Z]` matches `A` `_` `Z`

---

If you want to match a single uppercase char A-Z and an optional digit 1-9

```
^[A-Z][1-9]?\) [^:\n]*:.*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]` Match a single char A-Z
- `[1-9]?\)`  Opionally match a digit 1-9 and `)` followed by a space
- `[^:\n]*` Optionally repeat matching any character except `:` or a newline
- `:.*` Match `:` and the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vehcqJ/1)

Comment: This is it. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex pattern:

```regex
^[A-Z]+[0-9]*\) .*:.*$
```

### Demo

Comment: This is close, but it wouldn't match the second line I provided, which has a number before the parentheses.

Comment: I have fixed my answer.